# Why Zeeman coupling can be used in Bogoliubov-De Gennes superconducting Hamiltonian and Josephson junctions model for Majorana?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-insulators

It is well-known that type-1 superconductivity holds perfect diamagnetism, which means that magnetic field is expelled by the superconductor.
However, there are cases, especially in the topological superconductivity field, that magnetic fields are included in the Hamiltonian of a crystal, in the form of Zeeman coupling, together with a superconducting pairing.
My question is: how these two concepts can stand together? It is trivial that I can write a Zeeman term for a system below the critical temperature?

Here I attach some references in papers that do this:
https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.96.205425
https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.100.094526